# What is the appropriate value for adSize in the xml file if I want to include an InterstitialAd and not a Banner?

Tags: android, xml, admob

What is the appropriate value for adSize in the xml file if I want to include an InterstitialAd and not a Banner?

My problem is that including an InterstitialAd from Admin to my application does not work properly.

So far I followed the official tutorial, but it says nothing about the value of ads:adSize in the xml. When I implemented a ad with a banner this attribute was set with "BANNER" but I suppose this is not the solution when I want to have an Interstitial ad.

So could you please tell me which other values than BANNER are possible for ads:adSize or what else I should use to make it work?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code required only when you want to add banner view at your App view.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Follow instruction of this [link](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) to implement InterstitialAd in your App.

Comment: Thank you, I already used this tutorial. Do I understand correctly that for an Interstitial there is no tag in the xml file?

Comment: Great help, I just had to delete it out of the xml and it works perfectly!